# JSF Custom Component for jQueryUI Drag / Drop

Tags: jsf-2, custom-component

I'm learning to build JSF Custom Components and I thought I could try and build an implementation of jQuery's Drag & Drop.. So I read most of what's out there and could actually build a simple enough Draggable and Droppable component that basically generate the right amount of jQuery js to support Drag & Drop up until I can associate the "draggable" object and the "droppable" container and pretty much drag / drop things around..

This was fairly simple, my problem is how to get the "data" of what's being dropped, or how to bind to the drop event that jQuery Generates... I know it should be easy enough, so if anyone could point me in the right direction (documentations / code sample) I would very much appreciate it...

I will paste as little code as I think I have to.. just so you can see what I did.. I can share the lot (it's not much more that what's pasted really..) if anyone needs it...

(As you can see I can bind an ajax event.. I just can't figure out how to call it.. ).

TIA..

Components...

```
@FacesComponent(Draggable.COMPONENT_TYPE)
public class Draggable extends UIComponentBase  {
    public static final String COMPONENT_TYPE = "ar.com.easytech.Draggable";
    public static final String DEFAULT_RENDERER_TYPE = "ar.com.easytech.DraggableRenderer";
    public static final String COMPONENT_FAMILY = "javax.faces.Output";

    public String getFamily() {
        return COMPONENT_FAMILY;
    }

    public String getFor() {
        return (String) getStateHelper().eval(PropertyKeys.forVal);
    }

    ...

    protected enum PropertyKeys {
        forVal("for"), draggableSelector, revert, containTo;
        String c;

        PropertyKeys() {
        }

        PropertyKeys(String c) {
            this.c = c;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return ((this.c != null) ? this.c : super.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void encodeEnd(FacesContext facesContext) throws IOException {
        ResponseWriter writer = facesContext.getResponseWriter();

        String clientId = getClientId(facesContext);
        UIComponent targetComponent = findComponent(getFor());
        if(targetComponent == null)
            throw new FacesException("Cannot find component \"" + getFor());

        String target = targetComponent.getClientId();

        writer.startElement("script", null);
        writer.writeAttribute("id", clientId + "_s", null);
        writer.writeAttribute("type", "text/javascript", null);
        writer.write("$(function() {");
        writer.write("$( '#" + target.replace(":", "\\\\:") + "').draggable({");
        if (getRevert() != null) writer.write(" revert: '" + getRevert() + "', ");
        if (getContainTo() != null) writer.write(" containment: '" + getContainTo() + "',");
        writer.write("});");

        writer.write("});");
        writer.endElement("script");
    }

}
```

Droppable.java

```
@FacesComponent(Droppable.COMPONENT_TYPE)
public class Droppable extends UIComponentBase implements ClientBehaviorHolder {
    public static final String COMPONENT_TYPE = "ar.com.easytech.Droppable";
    public static final String DEFAULT_RENDERER_TYPE = "ar.com.easytech.DroppableRenderer";
    public static final String COMPONENT_FAMILY = "javax.faces.Output";

    private final static String DEFAULT_EVENT = "drop";
    private static final Collection<String> EVENT_NAMES = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(Arrays.asList(DEFAULT_EVENT));

    public String getFamily() {
        return COMPONENT_FAMILY;
    }

    // Property: for
    public String getFor() {
        return (String) getStateHelper().eval(PropertyKeys.forVal);
    }

    ...

    protected enum PropertyKeys {
        forVal("for"), droppableSelector, activeClass, hoverClass, accept, tolerance, source;
        String c;

        PropertyKeys() {
        }

        // Constructor needed by "for" property
        PropertyKeys(String c) {
            this.c = c;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return ((this.c != null) ? this.c : super.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void queueEvent(FacesEvent event) {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        if (isRequestSource(context)) {
            Map<String, String> params = context.getExternalContext()
                    .getRequestParameterMap();
            String eventName = params.get("javax.faces.behavior.event");
            String clientId = getClientId(context);

            AjaxBehaviorEvent behaviorEvent = (AjaxBehaviorEvent) event;

            if (eventName.equals("drop")) {
                String dragId = params.get(clientId + "_sourceId");
                String dropId = params.get(clientId + "_targetId");
                DragDropEvent dndEvent = null;
                String datasourceId = getSource();

                if (datasourceId != null) {
                    UIData datasource = (UIData) findComponent(datasourceId);
                    String[] idTokens = dragId.split(String
                            .valueOf(UINamingContainer
                                    .getSeparatorChar(context)));
                    int rowIndex = Integer
                            .parseInt(idTokens[idTokens.length - 2]);
                    datasource.setRowIndex(rowIndex);
                    Object data = datasource.getRowData();
                    datasource.setRowIndex(-1);

                    dndEvent = new DragDropEvent(this,
                            behaviorEvent.getBehavior(), dragId, dropId, data);
                } else {
                    dndEvent = new DragDropEvent(this,
                            behaviorEvent.getBehavior(), dragId, dropId);
                }

                super.queueEvent(dndEvent);
            }

        } else {
            super.queueEvent(event);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<String> getEventNames() {
        return EVENT_NAMES;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDefaultEventName() {
        return DEFAULT_EVENT;
    }

    @Override
    public void decode(FacesContext context) {

         if (context == null ) {
              throw new NullPointerException();
            }

            String clientId = getClientId(context);
            Map<String, String> requestParameterMap = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
            String value = (String) requestParameterMap.get(clientId);
            if (value == null || value.equals("") || !clientId.equals(value))
              return;
            ActionEvent actionEvent = new ActionEvent(this);
            queueEvent(actionEvent);
    }

    @Override
    public void encodeEnd(FacesContext context) throws IOException {

        ClientBehaviorContext behaviorContext =
                  ClientBehaviorContext.createClientBehaviorContext(context,this, DEFAULT_EVENT, getClientId(context), null);

        ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
        String clientId = getClientId(context);
        UIComponent targetComponent = findComponent(getFor());
        if(targetComponent == null)
            throw new FacesException("Cannot find component \"" + getFor());
        String target = targetComponent.getClientId();

        writer.startElement("script", null);
        writer.writeAttribute("id", clientId + "_s", null);
        writer.writeAttribute("type", "text/javascript", null);
        writer.write("$(function() {");
        writer.write("$( '#" + target.replace(":", "\\\\:") + "').droppable({");

        if (getActiveClass() != null) writer.write(" activeClass: '" + getActiveClass() + "',");
        if (getHoverClass() != null) writer.write(" hoverClass: '" + getHoverClass() + "',");
        if (getAccept() != null) writer.write(" accept: '" + getAccept() + "',");
        if (getTolerance() != null) writer.write(" tolerance: '" + getTolerance() + "',");

        Map<String,List<ClientBehavior>> behaviors = getClientBehaviors();
        if (behaviors.containsKey(DEFAULT_EVENT) ) {
            String drop = behaviors.get(DEFAULT_EVENT).get(0).getScript(behaviorContext);
            writer.writeAttribute("drop:", drop, null);
        }

        writer.write("});");
        writer.write("});");
        writer.endElement("script");
    }

    // Private

    private boolean isRequestSource(FacesContext context) {
        return this.getClientId(context).equals(context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap() .get("javax.faces.source"));
    }
}
```

And the usage for this would be something like..

```
<h:form id="frm">
      <div id="container" class="container">
        <ui:repeat var="row" value="#{homeBean.data}" id="dnd" >
          <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="draggable" styleClass="draggable">
            <h:outputText value="#{row}" />
          </h:panelGroup>
          <et:draggable  for="draggable" draggableSelector=".draggable" containTo="parent" revert="invalid" />
        </ui:repeat>

        <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="droppable" styleClass="droppable">
          <p>Drop Here!</p>
        </h:panelGroup>
      </div>

  <h:dataTable id="selectedItems" var="data" value="#{homeBean.selectedRows}">
    <h:column>
      <h:outputText value="#{data.name}" />
    </h:column>
  </h:dataTable>

      <et:droppable for="droppable" droppableSelector=".droppable" hoverClass="ui-state-hover" activeClass="ui-state-active" >
         <f:ajax listener="#{homeBean.objectDropped}" render="@form" event="drop" />
      </et:droppable>
    </h:form>
```

HomeBean.java

```
@ManagedBean
public class HomeBean {


    private List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<String> selectedRows = new ArrayList<String>();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        data.add("Value 1");
        data.add("Value 2");
    }

    public void objectDropped(DragDropEvent event) {
        selectedRows.add(event.getSourceId());
    }

    public List<String> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<String> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public List<String> getSelectedRows() {
        return selectedRows;
    }

    public void setSelectedRows(List<String> selectedRows) {
        this.selectedRows = selectedRows;
    }


}
```

Comment: do you mean sortable ?like this ? http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

Comment: @Daniel, I actually need one step before, I need to bind the jQuery drop event  `$( ".selector" ).bind( "drop", function(event, ui) {
  ...
});` so I can create my custom (well.. it actually ended up just like PrimeFaces....) DragDropEvent and call de BB to do something with the dropped item..

Comment: hi @FMQ, I am also very interested in making custom drag&drop component in JSF. Could you please share me some experience how to do it, or maybe some tutorial or documentation would be very appreciate. Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

To your example, this is one way to pass data from jquery event via JSF to the server (its self explanatory INMO)

```
$( ".selector" ).bind( "drop", function(event, ui) { 
    $("#myInputHiddenID").val("someJsonStringCanBePlacedHereForExample");
    $("#myButtonID").click();
});


<h:commandButton id="myButtonID" action="#{myBean.myAction()}" style="display:none" >
    <f:ajax></f:ajax>
    <h:inputHidden id="myInputHiddenID" value="#{myBean.myStringData}" />
</h:commandButton>

public void myAction() {
     System.out.println(myStringData);
}
```

Comment: @Daniel.. yes... this should work but I'm actually trying to achieve this within the Custom Component that I'm creating.. for example PrimeFaces generates this code for the "drop" event `$(function() {PrimeFaces.cw('Droppable','widget_carForm_j_idt35',{id:'carForm:j_idt35',target:'carForm:selectedCars',activeClass:'ui-state-highlight',onDrop:handleDrop,tolerance:'touch',behaviors:{drop:function(event) {PrimeFaces.ab({source:'carForm:j_idt35',event:'drop',process:'carForm:j_idt35',update:'carForm:dropArea carForm:availableCars'}, arguments[1]);}}});});` and this generates a DragDropEvent...

Comment: this part os the part that I can't understand how it's linked with my component... my explanation of my problem might not be clear .. if so.. please let me know so I can try and clarify my problem...Thanks!

Comment: dunno, looks like some constructor (`cw`) , try debugging the js then... put break point inside the `cw` (or place `debugger;` inside the function) and debug the code to understand more...

Answer (score 0):

As it turn´s out, what I was missing is adding an Ajax Call on jQuery drop event that raises the "drop" event defined in Droppable.java....

```
writer.write(" jsf.ajax.request(this,event,{execute: '");
writer.write(getClientId() +"', sourceId: ui.draggable.attr('id') , targetId: $(this).attr('id')}); ");
```

I still have an issue with the event generated (It does not generate an instance of javax.faces.behavior.event) but I guess I should open a new question for this...